# Mutithreaded / multiprocess command line ftp client for Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, ftp, wget, multi-threaded

I am searching for command line ftp client for Windows, capable of speeding up downloads by using multiple processes/threads. (Filezilla does it AFAIK, but it does not work from command line).

Or maybe there is a way to do it with `wget` (which I am currently using)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [aria2c](http://aria2.sourceforge.net/).

```
aria2 is a lightweight multi-protocol & multi-source download utility operated
in command-line. It supports HTTP/HTTPS, FTP, BitTorrent and Metalink. aria2 has
built-in JSON-RPC and XML-RPC interface. You can manipulate aria2 via these
interfaces.
```

It supports multiple connections to the same or different sources, resumable download, multiple protocols, etc.
I used it on Windows and Linux and works really well.

Answer (score 0):

http://puf.sourceforge.net/

> puf is a download tool for UNIX-like systems. You may use it to download single files or to mirror entire servers. It is similar to GNU wget (and has a partly compatible command line), but has the ability to do many downloads in parallel. This is very interesting, if you have a high-bandwidth internet connection.

I've not tried it. No idea if it can compile on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

well you can open another cmd window or use start "" wget URL (which runs it in another cmd window).. either way those are of course separate threads. And they'll download together.